# Prove: $B\subset E\in\mathcal{M}$ should have a corresponding $[a,b]$ such that the measure of $B$ is arbitrarily close to $b-a$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

First of all, I am searching specifically for a **constructive proof**. I already have a proof by contradiction.

Here is the question:

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Prove that if $m(E)>0$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists interval $[a,b]$ such that
$$m(E\cap[a,b]) > (1-\epsilon)\cdot(b-a)$$

Here is what I came up with. I took inspiration from binary search.

---

First let write
$$E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} E\cap[n,n+1]$$
Then notice that it must be the case that there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $0<m(E\cap[n,n+1])$. Let $B_1 = E\cap[n,n+1]$ such that we have $0<m(B_1) = k_1<\infty$

Consider $a_1 = \inf B_1$, $b_1 =\sup B_1$ and the interval $[a_1 , b_1 ]$. Then
$$m(E\cap [a_1 , b_1 ]) = \delta_{k_1} (b_1 - a_1) \quad 0< \delta_{k_1} \leq 1$$

Now, divide $B_1$ in half by considering 
$$B_- = \left\{ b\in B_1 : b < \frac{b_1-a_1}{2}  \right\}$$ 
$$B_+ = \left\{ b\in B_1 : b > \frac{b_1-a_1}{2}  \right\}$$

And take as $B_2 = \begin{cases} B_- & m(B_-) \geq m(B_+) \\ B_+ & otherwise \end{cases}$

Notice that $(b_2 - a_2) = \frac{1}{2}(b_1 - a_1)$, but $m(B_2) \geq \frac{1}{2}m(B_1)$
and hence, for,
$$m(E\cap [a_2 , b_2 ]) = \delta_{k_2} (b_2 - a_2) \quad 0< \delta_{k_1} \leq 1$$
we have that $\delta_{k_2} \geq \delta_{k_1}$.

Repeating the process, results in $\delta_{k_n} \to (1-\epsilon)$ as $n\to\infty$.

To see this, suppose by contradiction that this was not the case. Suppose that
$\delta_{k_n}$ stays constant after some $n_0$ iterations. First note that this means that the elements of $B_{n_0}$ are evenly spread out over the interval $[a_{n_0},b_{n_0}]$. Note that a
union of rectangles of length $b_n-a_n$, touching each other, can be used as a cover of $B_{n_0}$. But it will always be the case that the sum of volumes of such a cover will be equal to $\delta_{k_n}m(B_{n_0})$. Hence, also the infimum is equal to
$\delta_{k_n}m(B_{n_0})$, and thus, $\delta_{k_n}$ for $n\geq n_0$ must be equal to $1$ since the infinitum of this particular cover has volume, as most, equal to any other cover of $B_{n_0}$. To see that the last statement is correct, consider any other cover, take, the smallest $R$ in such a cover and then let $n$ be big enough such that $\mathcal{l}(R)>\mathcal{l}([a_n,b_n])$.

Please give me your thoughts on whether you think this proof is valid, incorrect by has potential, or hopeless.

Comment: How do you know that $a_1,b_1$ are finite?

Comment: @uniquesolution, Yeah, that's a mistake. But I think it can be fixed. Cannot you always take $B_1$ such that $a_1$ and $b_1$ are finite? We can say $E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} [n, n+1]\cap E$ and then one of those sets that make up the union must have measure greater than zero. Take that set as $B_1$

Comment: This is the Lebesgue Density Theorem. [Here](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~grzes/dydaktyka16_17/short_proof.pdf) is an elementary (constructive) proof.

Comment: How do you find the $n$ near the top of the proof, and how do you know that the suprema in question exist? There are many issues with constructive proofs that do not seem to be considered here.

Comment: @Chilango Incomprendido: the first Lemma on the second page appears to use trichotomy of the reals, which is not constructively valid.

Comment: @Carl Mummert I guess philosophically my proof doesn't count as "constructive". I was immediately aware of this issue. But it still gives more intuition about the nature of [a,b] than a proof by contradiction. I guess you could write an algorithm using this proof, first to find n by just going over the intervals successively and then to find [a,b]. I'm aware that it might be the case that such an algorithm will run forever without finding the necessary n and [a,b].